# PresentViewController From AppDelegate handleActionWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, presentviewcontroller

Is it possible to present a view controller from the AppDelegate method `handleActionWithIdentifier`?

I am registering action categories similar to below:

```
action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[action1 setTitle:@"Tweet"];
[action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
[action1 setDestructive:NO];
[action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];
```

When my remote notification arrives I can pull down or swipe left on the home screen to see the text "Tweet"

My `handleActionWithIdentifier` method is very simple:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting this is awesome!"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }

    if (completionHandler) {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```

However when I click the "Tweet" action category from my notification it does nothing. It doesn't bring up the Twitter tweet now window.

I don't want the app to have to open in order to have this action occur. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppDelegate action handlers are only meant to perform background operations, only launching the app for short amount of time, performing the block on a background thread then backgrounding the app again. Be sure to read the apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:

For your example instead of presenting the tweet view controller you'll need to directly send the tweet without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = tweetSheet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting this is awesome!"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{}];
}

if (completionHandler) {

    completionHandler();
}
```

}